Получение количества товара в наличие woocommerce
Мне нужно получить сколько в данный момент есть определённого товара (по id или артикулу) на складе в WooCommerce. Как это сделать?


нужно получить сколько в данный момент есть определённого товара (по
id или артикулу)

Как-то так
  $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
  return $product->get_stock_quantity()

